# What exactly is '$this" in add_action()

Tags: php, wordpress, this, action

Some add_action() statements that i see now and then are provided with an array in which the first argument is $this, and the second one, the function.

As far as i know, $this stands as the current instance in POO, but what about in this particular case? Let's say for the sake of example that we have a newsletter system that registers your email adress, except if it still exists in the database.

```
<?php
public function save_email()
{
    if (isset($_POST['zero_newsletter_email']) && !empty($_POST['zero_newsletter_email'])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $email = $_POST['zero_newsletter_email'];

        $row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}zero_newsletter_email WHERE email = '$email'");
        if (is_null($row)) {
            $wpdb->insert("{$wpdb->prefix}zero_newsletter_email", array('email' => $email));
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need to declare it as an available action. why should we need an array like this one?

```
add_action('wp_loaded', array($this, 'save_email'));
```

And why couldn't we simply do as followed?

```
add_action('wp_loaded','save_email');
```

Comment: `$this` is the current instance of the current class.  So it would be the instance invoking the hook.  Or the class the action is being added in.

Answer (score 1):

Because `save_email` is a class method and we're adding the action from `$this` class instance (i.e. from within the class owning the method).

The array represents a PHP callable, see type 3 in the example: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, glad you helped me to put some rationality on this confusing statement. Good to know !

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

`$this` is the current instance of the current class. So it would be the instance invoking the hook. Or the class the action is being added in.

```
add_action('wp_loaded', array($this, 'save_email'));
```

So this is the save email in the current class.

> And why couldn't we simply do as followed?
>
> `add_action('wp_loaded','save_email');`

Because you can't ... Just kidding.

this is due to using `call_user_func_array`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Which is the built in way of doing it.  I am sure it also has to do with how functions are called, because without the class it would be ambiguous if this was a function or a method of a class.

In the case you present, PHP would think that was a function.  Even if there was a way to tell it, it wasn't, how would you tell it what class that method is in.  So it's easier and safer to just put the class in...

Comment: you can't because you can't because you can't

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the feedback. I'll just take it as an internal logic cog and assume that it's how it's suppose to be

Comment: you can also use `[__CLASS__, 'method']` if you want a fresh instance.  And for a static you can do `__CLASS__.'::method'`  Without those we could only do functions, (if you call a Closure a function)

Comment: Interresting ! also, i assume that situations where you need a fresh instance for that matter is pretty much edge case, but it's always nice to have in mind that it's possible

Comment: yea `__CLASS__` is just a magic constant for the full class name (namespace and class) of the current class.  You could type it in as well.  Now you can also do `Someclass::class` which is supper nice.